# Android Emulator support for Windows touchscreen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have a Surface Pro 3 laptop/tablet, which runs Windows 10 and I sometimes use it for programming. I'm using Android emulator which comes with Android Studio, and performance-wise it's pretty good, but I have a problem with touch controls.

Since my device has a touchscreen I am able to perform gestures like swiping or two-finger pinch to zoom, but the emulator doesn't recognize these. Also, long press is recognized as right mouse click (and on Windows desktop apps it should work like that).

Is there a way to configure AVD emulator to recognize these touch events as they are, or is there another emulator program that does?

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use the `Visual Studio Emulator for Android` and it works just fine with my Surface Book https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx